# Program skips over one condition in the loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end

def move
  while true
    puts "Hit or stick?"
    input = gets.chomp
    if input == "hit" or input == "stick"
      return input
    end
  end
end

def score(cards)
  hash = {
    2 => ["two"],
    3 => ["three"],
    4 => ["four"],
    5 => ["five"],
    6 => ["six"],
    7 => ["seven"],
    8 => ["eight"],
    9 => ["nine"],
    10 => ["ten", "jack", "queen", "king"],
    11 => ["ace"]
  }
  
  total = 0
  cards.each do |x|
    hash.each do |key, value|
      value.each do |z|
        if z == x
          total += key.to_i
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return total
end

def run_game
  cards = []
  loop do
    entry = move
    if entry == "hit"
      cards.push(random_card)
      puts ("Score so far: #{score(cards)}")
    elsif entry == "stick"
      if score(cards) > 21
        return "You busted with: #{score(cards)} "
      else
        return "You Scored: #{score(cards)} "
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Everything seems to be working well except for when I type in "stick"; terminal just ends the program. I cant get the "You busted with: #{score(cards)} " or "You Scored: #{score(cards)} " output. Could someone please play with my code, I'm out of ideas what's wrong here..

Comment: Please don't throw down code and expect readers to figure out what you are trying to do. Most could figure it out but it would be such a poor use of their time they are likely to just move on to the next question. Always start your questions with an explanation of what you wish to accomplish with the code that follows.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change both `return` for `print` (or similar) otherwise, your code will return from `run_game` when entry is equal to "stick" and if you're not working and/or holding that value you won't see it anywhere.

Comment: I just did that and yeah, got desired output, thanks! But now Im in infinite loop and I dont know how to stop it. Tried putting 'break' right after last 'elsif' and then after last 'else' but I keep getting errors

Comment: Tried also change the 'loop do' in run_game to 'until entry == "stick" ' with the same result

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `print` to have cleaner output (`puts` is adding a carriage return). To fix the infinite loop issue, you can just put a `break` after the line "You busted ..."

Comment: nah, it didn't help :(

Comment: `if score(cards) > 21
        puts "You busted with: #{score(cards)} "
        break
      else
        puts "You Scored: #{score(cards)} "
        break
      end` that does. Make sure you read Cary's comment.